# How to externalize a tcolorbox to produce a PNG file useable for htlatex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, externalize

The following code produces a picture of a tcolorbox that contains an axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
Test
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textbf{Test picture}]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel = \textbf{y}
]
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\textit{Test caption.}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

My end goal is to have everything encapsulated to be exported as a PNG file. How can I accomplish this? I know tikz provides an externalize option but surrounding the tcolorbox with tikzpicture leads to all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your actual goal here, but I've found a solution that allows you to externalise the `tcolorbox` with its `tikzpicture` *without* surrounding it in another `tikzpicture` (as that causes no end of difficulties).

It turns out that the `tcolorbox` package has its own externalisation feature that can be applied a bit more broadly than the `external` library with TikZ (but is a little less sophisticated).  It is documented in Section 24 (*Library external*) of the `tcolorbox` documentation.

Here's an example based on your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585622/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{external}

\tcbset{external/prefix=tcbext_}
\tcbEXTERNALIZE
\begin{document}
Test
\begin{tcbexternal}{boxedaxes}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textbf{Test picture (text not visible)}]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel = \textbf{y}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\textit{Test caption (text not visible).}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbexternal}

\end{document}
```

This produces a separate PDF, called `tcbext_boxedaxes.pdf`, which looks like the following:

[image: Externalised tcolorbox]

Comment: Wow, that works great! Yes, much more elegant! Awesome, thanks! :) 

It even works flawlessly in connection with htlatex. The HTML output shows the right image without any further need for adjustment. This way, I can show the same tcolorbox both for the PDF output as well as the HTML output. I'm using the HTML output for websites or for ebooks.

Comment: @ClemensLode Given that this is what you actually needed, how about editing the question so that it fits better?  Something like "How can I externalise a section of text without putting it in a tikzpicture?"

Comment: Done! I removed the "text not visible" parts, though, as they might be confusing.

Comment: @ClemensLode Brilliant! It's now much easier for others who might have a similar question to find.  I'll edit my example to remove the `text not visible` bits as well so that it matches what you have.

Comment: Also, I'm going to remove my comments on your question as they are no longer relevant.  You might want to then remove your comment there as it might not make sense without mine that it was a reply to.